# Java :calculate the circle diameter and

Tags: java

this is a Class about calculating diameter,circumference and area of circle that user enter radius value and it gives him diameter,cirucumf... ,

**this is the class code:**

```
package circle;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Circle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        int radius=0;
        int diameter;
        int circumference ;
        int area;
        int Pi;

        Pi=(int) 3.14;

        area = (int) (radius*radius*Pi);
        circumference =(int)(radius*2*Pi);
        diameter = (int)(radius*2);

        System.out.print("Enter radius value:");
        radius=input.nextInt();

        System.out.printf("area is %d%n" , area);
        System.out.printf("diameter is %d%n", diameter);
        System.out.printf("circumference is %d%n", environment);
    } 
}
```

this is what output gives me :

> Enter radius value: (for exmaple) 4
>
> area is 0             //  (real value is 50.24)
>
> diameter is 0         //  (8)
>
> circumference is 0        //(25.12)

what is the code problem?
or how can i fix it?

Comment: Could you please edit your question and format the code (and fix the typos)?

Comment: When you calculate all values, you have not read user input, thus all calculations multiply by zero. (`int radius=0;`)

Comment: Why do you use `int` everywhere instead of `double`? `(int) 3.14` will be converted to 3 immediately.

Comment: radius is set to zero , which when multiplied by any other number gives zero as an answer, plus you are calculating before reading the input which you don't use

Comment: Ah, you seem a fan of declarative programming. Unfortunately Java is imperative language. Statements are executed one at a time, in order of the program flow. Running the code under debugger would greatly help you understand how things work in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"environment" will be replaced by "circumference". As your excepted output is decimal value. So use float/double instead of int. In your program you are calculating diameter,circumference and area after initialising the value of radius(radius=0) but before getting the value of radius(radius=4). I have modified your code. It seem help you.

```
package circle;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Circle {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int radius=0;
    float diameter;
    double circumference ;
    double area;
    double Pi;

    Pi= 3.14;



    System.out.print("Enter radius value:");
    radius=input.nextInt();

    area = (radius*radius*Pi);
    circumference =(radius*2*Pi);
    diameter = (radius*2);

    System.out.printf("area is " + area);
    System.out.printf("\ndiameter is "+ diameter);
    System.out.printf("\ncircumference is "+ circumference);
} 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You read the radius AFTER computing area/environment(?)/diameter. Furthermore, your values are `int` variables, which also means that your value for pi is just `3`. I suggest you correct the order of the statements, and start using `double` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

you are calculating the values area/environment(?)/diameter before getting and initializing the radius input.And at that time the default value for radius is set which is 0. Hence it is giving the results of all the parameters as 0.So you will have to re order your code as below:

```
System.out.print("Enter radius value:");
radius=input.nextInt();

area = (int) (radius*radius*Pi);
environment=(int)(radius*2*Pi);
diameter = (int)(radius*2);

System.out.printf("area is %d%n" , area);
System.out.printf("diameter is %d%n", diameter);
System.out.printf("environment is %d%n", environment);
```